# Is it possible to get other eeveelutions in Let's Go?

Tags: pokemon-lets-go

I know that pokemon LGP/LGE is a remake of the gen 1 games that only had eevee evolve into vaporeon, jolteon, and flareon, but lets say i wanted leafeon for example. Would you be able to at least transfer that leafeon from another game into this one? Or is there a way to get it ingame?
Just wondering!

Comment: If my post has answered your question, don't forgot to accept by clicking on the check mark next to it :) Be sure to do that with any of your other questions. I noticed you have a few that seem to have been answered

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately no. As you stated, the Let's Go series only support Generation 1 Pokémon (with the exception of Meltan and Melmetal, which were released in Generation 7). Therefore, you cannot obtain any other Eeveelution aside from Vaporeon, Jolteon, and Flareon.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Thats a shame, though. The gen 1 eeveelutions arent exactly my favorite

Comment: Note this also applies to Pokemon which gained an evolution in newer games, like Chansey and Onix

Comment: *Let's Go: Eevee* quasi-sort-of-but-not-really breaks this answer. While your partner Eevee can't evolve, it can learn some special moves that all match the various types Eevee can evolve into, so Eevee has a really wide range of flexibility. And, each of those moves has a secondary effect (fire burns, grass seeds the target, fairy clears status effects, etc). That's about as close as you can get to getting the non-Kanto Eeveelutions.

Comment: @Ellesedil sure, but whats a sylveon without its ribbons?